# Tablet Media query does not work

Tags: css, media-queries

This does not work:

```
@media only screen  and (min-device-width : 768px)  and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
```

Comment: Provide more information. What doesn't work? __What is your question?__

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've added  to the head of the html page you're trying to edit with media queries.